# Junit Testing for an Android Activity

Tags: android, testing

Does any one have any experience with creating unit-test for the On Create and `OnClick` method in java, using Android Studio? I use data from my `Firebasedatabase`. 
I think I have to use Mock-object, but I don't knot where to start.

Under is the code from my class `LoginActivity`

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mfireBaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
        textViewSignUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);

        buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonSignIn){
            usersignin();

        }
        if(v==textViewSignUp){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
       }

    private void usersignin() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Logging in. Please wait...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mfireBaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    getSignedInUserProfile();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getSignedInUserProfile() {

        DatabaseReference reference = mDatabase;//.child("eduback-2feef");
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = firebaseUser.getUid();
        reference.child("Users").child(userID).child("User info").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if(user != null) {
                    // Save if the user is student or prof in shared prefs.
                    PreferenceHelper helper = new PreferenceHelper(getBaseContext());
                    helper.setIsStudent(user.isStudent);
                    checkStudentOrProfessor(user);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Ups vis error
            }
        });



    }

    private void checkStudentOrProfessor(User user) {

        Intent i;
        if (user.isStudent ) {
            i = new Intent(this, MainActivityStudent.class);
        } else {
            i = new Intent(this, MainActivityProfessor.class);
        }
        startActivity(i);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mockito mocking framework for Java  offers compatibility with Android unit testing.

You can configure mock objects to return some specific value when invoked.

You don't need to test Firebasedatabass.

But you have to make Firebasedatabase wrapper class for yours view

Wrapper class have to include variable(userID, user.isStudent)

Comment: Can you give me an example?